# Elasticsearch - Match all arraylist field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I have few documents with array "items" , i want to only pick those documents where "items.name" is equal to "red". If there is any document with one red and another color, then it should not come in result.

1.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "blue"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. 

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. 

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, here i need a query where only document 2 and 3 should come in result, as "red" is present in all the "items.name". document 1 is ignored as it contains blue also.

Comment: Are you sure about the last document?. ON the last one, it has 2 red items.

Comment: Yes, both name will be same, there will be some more fields, i have removed for simplicity. Query should be able to pick only that documents where all the "items.name" matches "red"

Comment: Okay, I see. Did you try to use the script for this?

Comment: yes I saw some examples but, didn't tried, thinking if possible by normal elastic query to do something

Comment: Let me write a solution with a script, and then we can improve it with normal query also if we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my first solution with the script :

```
GET test/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "all_red_items": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "script": {
        "source": "int count = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc['items.name'].size(); i++) { if (doc['items.name'][i] != 'red') { count++ }} emit(count == 0);"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "all_red_items": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my regular expression solution :

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "items.name": {
              "value": "red"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "items.name": "@&~(red)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Before going to send the request, you need to prepare your index below :

```
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST test/_doc
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "blue"
    }
  ]
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "red"
    }
  ]
}


POST test/_doc
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "red"
    }
  ]
}

GET test/_mapping
```

Comment: For the script, I could not optimize it. Maybe we can write a more optimized script there to make fast results. Even we can remove for a loop.

Comment: Here without for loop. But I could not be sure that it will work for every case or not. You can check both of them : 

`source": "emit(doc['items.id'].size() == 1 && doc['items.name'][0] == 'red');"`

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstand the question. For this reason I changed the script a little bit again.

Comment: The previous query returned document 2 only. But now, The result is document 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you so much, let me check this

Comment: Added also regular expression solution. FYI.